# Robomongo displaying extra characters for each entity of the json output

Tags: json, mongodb-query, robo3t

db..find()

returns

```
{
 [37m"_id"[m: ObjectId([33;4m"54f48057b89c173929000001"[m),
 [37m"created_at"[m: ISODate([34m"2015-03-02T15:23:03.038Z"[m),
 [37m"updated_at"[m: ISODate([34m"2015-03-10T19:20:14.702Z"[m),
}
```

How do I get rid of these extra characters -[37m  etc?

Comment: did you figured this out? I'm also getting this, and a ESC character too

Comment: No luck. If you query for one doc, then it displays as pretty, i.e.e db.<collection>.findOne()

Comment: I did find out why-- it was due to mongo-hacker --https://github.com/TylerBrock/mongo-hacker so I removed this.

Answer (score 0):

Found that Robomongo is not compatible with MongoDB 3.0 and up.

Check your mongo version with

```
$ mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7
```

As a alternative you can you [MongoChef](http://3t.io/mongochef/) that does work with mongo v3.0> and displays the data right